# Chrome Dev Tools how to view :hover state css of a pseudo element

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

on the chrome dev tools, you can view the hover state of elements but when I try to view the hover state of a pseudo-element the options are greyed out.
Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: I guess that's because it can't have such a state, only the actual element can have it.

Comment: but using CSS you can modify it's state

Comment: The element is modified e.g. it's `elem:hover::after` not the other way around.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying. I'm looking for a way to view the modify the state of the pseudo-element. are you saying the answer is that it's impossible?

Comment: Impossible because such a state doesn't exist, AFAICT.

Comment: Click the element itself first, not the pseudo-element, then force `:hover` state on it.

Comment: Hey, @wOxxOm I know I can click the element first but It won't show the CSS of the pseudo-element's `:hover` state. if I set something on `element:hover::after` It will show the CSS of the elements hover state but It won't show the css that is overwritten for the `:hover::after`

Comment: It works here. 1) select the element, 2) set the hover state, 3) select the pseudo-element.

Comment: Yeah it does. I never noticed it for some reason. Thanks. You should put an answer that says you have to have the hove state on the actual element.